# Class implementing two interfaces with same method?

Tags: java, methods, interface, abstract

```
/* Class name : Fish.java */
interface Fish 
{
   public void eat();
   public void travel();
}

/* Class name : Mammals.java */
interface Mammals 
{public void eat();
   public void travel();}
/*Amphibians mean living two lives (on land as well as on water). */
```

/*Main Class*/

```
public class Amphibians implements Mammals,Fish
 {
     public void eat()
   {          
   System.out.println("Amphibians eating");
   }
       public void travel()
   {
      System.out.println("Amphibians traveling");
   } 

/*Main Method*/
   public static void main(String args[])
 {
      Amphibians a = new Amphibians();
      a.eat();
      a.travel();
   }
```

}

Here interface implements in this class.Basically interface inheritances two or more class but here both different class in same method use then both method which way implement in one class. Please check error correct code.

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: Do you want a class that implements both interfaces?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear but suresh atta answer is what you are looking at i think

Comment: I have changed the question title to reflect what you are asking. Check if it is what you meant. If not I can revert it back.

Comment: I do not think it's good practive to downvote a question because of bad English -- the example code leaves room for interpretation but the different possible questions ( ;-) ) by themselves are not silly, it's just the English that is very hard to understand. Funny enough all different interpretations have been answered! :)

Comment: hochi, I disagree, the code runs and there's nothing clearly wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create interface inheritance, you can do it like this:

```
public interface Birds extends Animal
```

Now, by implementing `Birds` you'll have all of `Bird`'s methods plus the `Animal` ones. It shouldn't actually matter if a class implements `Animal` or `Bird` if the methods are the same, one particular class defines one behaviour.

For example, if ,say, a `Parrot` implements `travel` as an animal or as a `bird`, shouldn't it *fly* in both cases?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you failed to describe properly

You may want to write

```
public class MammalAni implements Animal,Birds{
```

Now your doubt is both `interfaces` have the same name method `eat()` and `travel()`.So you confused,how java executes them.

If you have two methods with same name in two interfaces,  and Some Class implemented with both the interfaces  then that one implementation acts for both the interface..

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am unsure about what you want to know. But if you want to know, can the class MammalAni implement both the interfaces. Then yes, but calling eat() or travel() for any of the interfaces will give the same result which is defined in the MammalAni class. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Interfaces methods must be implemented by the concrete class that
>   implements them.

Now suppose there are two interfaces then both say the same thing that concrete class must implement the method `eat()`.

Now in your case both `interface` say that concrete class must implement methods `eat()` and `travel()`. So when you implement both interfaces you only need a *single implementation*.

Suggestion:

```
public interface CanEat{
    public void eat();
}

public interface CanTravel{
    public void travel();
}

public interface Animal extends CanEat,CanTravel{
    //only methods specific for animal will be here
}

public interface Birds extends CanEat,CanTravel{
    //only methods specific to birds will be here like flying
}

So that tomorrow if you create a robotic Animal
public interface RoboticAnimal extends CanTravel{
   //no need for using CanEat interface as robot does not eat
}
```